# Select different counts as one select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a table Activity with this information:

```
+----------------------+---------------------+
| Task varchar(20)     | AddedDate datetime  | 
+----------------------+---------------------+
| Bought Donkey        | 2016-04-25 18:16:44 | 
| Fed Donkey           | 2016-04-18 18:16:44 | 
| Gave Donkey water    | 2016-04-03 18:16:44 | 
| Donkey race          | 2016-03-30 18:16:44 | 
| Donkey sleep         | 2016-03-12 18:16:44 | 
| Donkey did exercises | 2016-02-45 18:16:44 | 
| Took Donkey to shop  | 2016-01-05 18:16:44 | 
| Bought Cat           | 2015-12-19 18:16:44 | 
| Fed Cat              | 2015-12-14 18:16:44 | 
| Fed Donkey           | 2015-12-06 18:16:44 |
|                      |                     |
+----------------------+---------------------+
```

I want to count the tasks by animal by month
and output them like follows:

```
+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Animal       | 2016-04 | 2016-03 | 2016-02 | 2016-01 | 2015-12 |
+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Donkey       | 3       | 2       | 1       | 1       | 1       |    
| Cat          | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 2       |
|              |         |         |         |         |         |
+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I can get the counts by unioning lots of selects but its hardly efficient and it doesn't create a useable table-like display as above.

e.g.

```
select count(*)
from Activity
where month(AddedDate) = month(getdate()) - 1
and year(AddedDate) = 2016
and Task like '%Donkey%'
```

Furthermore it is for an SSRS so I would like it to automatically pick off the last 5 months, I have done something similar in this respect before however the select statements are getting the better of me.

Thanks in advance, all suggestions welcome.

Comment: If this is for an SSRS report, then use a `Matrix` in SSRS; it will be _much_ easier (and more dyniamc) than doing that aggregation in SQL.

Comment: Do you have any other indication of what the animal is other than by parsing the Task text?  What is the task was "Donkey kicked Cat"?

Comment: Haha!! I created the Donkey and Cat as an easy to explain representation of what I need to do, but yes, unfortunately I have to extract keywords from user inputted text. Thanks for your suggestion, I will look up Matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Activity TABLE (Task VARCHAR(20), AddedDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Activity VALUES
    ('Bought Donkey','2016-04-25 18:16:44'),
    ('Fed Donkey','2016-04-18 18:16:44'),
    ('Gave Donkey water','2016-04-03 18:16:44'),
    ('Donkey race','2016-03-30 18:16:44'),
    ('Donkey sleep','2016-03-12 18:16:44'),
    ('Donkey did exercises','2016-02-25 18:16:44'),
    ('Took Donkey to shop','2016-01-05 18:16:44'),
    ('Bought Cat','2015-12-19 18:16:44'),
    ('Fed Cat','2015-12-14 18:16:44'),
    ('Fed Donkey','2015-12-06 18:16:44')

;WITH Animal
    AS (
        SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN Task LIKE '%Donkey%' THEN 'Donkey'
                WHEN Task LIKE '%Cat%' THEN 'Cat'
                ELSE ''
                END AS Animal
                ,Task,AddedDate
        FROM @Activity
    )

SELECT Animal, LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,AddedDate,20),7) AS Date, COUNT(*) AS TaskCount
     FROM Animal
     GROUP BY Animal, LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,AddedDate,20),7)
```

From here, if you want to display it that way, you're going to have to use a pivot table. I'm not sure you can do that with everything open-ended, though. Alternately, you can pivot your own data. By the way, you can do this without a CTE; it just looks cumbersome, because I don't have the option of aliasing my GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Task LIKE '%Donkey%' THEN 'Donkey'
         WHEN Task LIKE '%Cat%' THEN 'Cat'
         ELSE ''    END AS Animal,
    LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,AddedDate,20),7) AS Date,
    COUNT(*) AS TaskCount
FROM @Activity
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Task LIKE '%Donkey%' THEN 'Donkey'
         WHEN Task LIKE '%Cat%' THEN 'Cat'
         ELSE ''    END, LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,AddedDate,20),7)
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, that's really useful